# Assign Category via Guest Entry Form

Tags: categories, plugins, guest

Is is possible to assign a category via a frontend Guest Entry form.

I tried

```
<input type="hidden" name="fieldHandle" value="SomeExistingCategorySlug">
```

But that did not work.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Simply put, a [Categories field](http://buildwithcraft.com/docs/categories-fields) is an array containing category ids, and your form needs to send it that way:

```twig
<input type="hidden" name="fields[fieldHandle][]" value="100">
```

Adding brackets to your field-handle [submits the value as an array](http://php.net/manual/en/faq.html.php#faq.html.arrays), and `100` is the id of the category.

Comment: Where do I find the category id?

Comment: You can either output it in your template: `{{ craft.categories.group('group_handle').slug('some_slug').first.id }}`, or go to "Backend -> Categories" inspect a category, and look for the `data-id` attribute.

Comment: I had tried using the data-id before I asked. Sorry, should have specified. Form sends, all data is recorded, just not the category.

Comment: Try creating a plugin with a [`guestEntries.beforeSave`-event](https://github.com/pixelandtonic/GuestEntries/#the-guestentriesbeforesave-event) and [dump-die](http://php.net/manual/de/function.var-dump.php) all the data, to check if it gets send correctly.

Comment: Replaced `name="fieldHandle[]"` with `name="fields[fieldHandle][]"` and Victor's solution worked.

Comment: @AbbeyDesign Thanks for pointing that out, overlooked that.