# Category as select dropdown box

Tags: categories, form

Im trying to setup a front end user form with a category as a select box.  The box looks right but when i submit the form i get a new entry and other fields are filled out but the catgory fields are blank?

This is for a fieldgroup named borough and the field on the section is also called bourough

```
<form method="post" action="" accept-charset="UTF-8">
  <input type="hidden" name="action" value="entries/saveEntry">
  <input type="hidden" name="redirect" value="account/jobs?added={id}">
  <input type="hidden" name="sectionId" value="9">
  <input type="hidden" name="enabled" value="0">

<!-- other form fields -->

  {% set boroughs = craft.categories.group('borough') %}

  <select name="fields[borough]" class="form-control">
       {% for category in boroughs %}
           <option value="{{category.id}}">
             {{category}}
           </option>
       {% endfor %}
  </select>
</form>
```

Comment: Probably the same problem as: [Assign Category via Guest Entry Form](http://craftcms.stackexchange.com/questions/1787/assign-category-via-guest-entry-form)

Comment: ahh yes... missing the extra [] that did it!  thanks

Comment: Can you add that as the official answer, @KeithMancuso?

Answer (score 5):

So looks like I was just missing the extra `[]` in the name.

```
fields[borough][]
```

Since categories are arrays the name also needed to be an array!