# Is it possible to add a category to an object through twig?

Tags: categories

I'm currently working on a registration page for users on a site.

There are two attributes that users may have on sign up that I need to reflect in the sign up process. (I will probably use checkboxes to indicate whether the user will have the categories assigned to them)

Currently, my idea to solve this is to have categories for users.

So, I have to ask first, is it even possible to set a category from a template? If so, how?

Comment: This looks like a duplicate of [this question](http://craftcms.stackexchange.com/questions/1787/assign-category-via-guest-entry-form) and [this question](http://craftcms.stackexchange.com/questions/2437/category-as-select-dropdown-box). See if those answer what your looking for.

Comment: Thank you very much, I can't believe I didn't find those on my own.

Should I delete this post?

Comment: Glad those answers worked. And no worries. Sometimes answers can be hard to find. Doesn't matter. I'll just flag this as a duplicate and it will get deleted.