# Front End Entry Form Select Dropdown Error

Tags: templating, form

My front-end new entry form works, but when I add the complexity of a dropdown to the mix - it error's and doesn't save the entry. (I found this out with trial and error, removing fields until I found the culprit - the dropdowns)

I'm unsure what errors it's returning, but I'm sure something may be off with the code.

```
  {% macro errorList(errors) %}
            {% if errors %}
                <ul class="errors">
                    {% for error in errors %}
                        <li>{{ error }}</li>
                    {% endfor %}
                </ul>
            {% endif %}
        {% endmacro %}

        {% from _self import errorList %}

        <form method="post" accept-charset="UTF-8" enctype="multipart/form-data">
            {{ csrfInput() }}
            <input type="hidden" name="action" value="entries/save-entry">
            {{ redirectInput('/listings/') }}
            <input type="hidden" name="sectionId" value="1">
            <input type="hidden" name="enabled" value="1">

            <div class="form-group">
              <label>Demographic</label>
              <select class="form-control" id="listingType" name="fields[demographic]">
                {% set demographicField = craft.fields.getFieldbyHandle('demographic') %}
                {% for option in demographicField.settings.options %}
                  <option>{{ option.label }}</option>
                {% endfor %}
              </select>
            </div>

            <button class="btn btn-primary btn-md semi-bold" type="submit">Create Listing</button>

        </form>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

On your dropdown field's `name`, you need a `[]` on the end for it to submit properly:

```
name="fields[demographic][]"
```

As mentioned in [this answer](https://craftcms.stackexchange.com/questions/1787/assign-category-via-guest-entry-form), the dropdown field is basically an array of options, so you need that empty array on the end for them to be stored in.